# How to loop through map and fetch only first few key value pairs and pass them to another function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, dictionary

I have a map which is having key value pairs as below:

```
map = 
    {
      "sha512-T9JWj==": [
        "mykey1597855209",
        "mykey159785520915978552101597855212"
      ],
      "sha512-lcddfd==": [
        "mykey15978552091597855210"
      ],
      "sha512-abcdfd==": [
        "otherkey15978552091597855210"
      ]
    }
```

I want to get the first key and pass it to another function `func1`.

Similarly I want to get all the values associated with that key and pass to a second function `func2`.

The map can have any number of key value pairs but I want to capture only first 10 key value pairs.

I am able to capture all keys and values using:

```
console.log(Object.keys(map));
console.log(Object.values(map));
```

How can I loop through the map and get the first key and pass it to `func1` and pass its values to `func2`?  I need to capture only `first 10 keys` and corresponding values.

```
1) Get only 10 keys and values from the the map object
2) Loop through first key value pair
3) Pass key to `func1`
4) Pass all values associated with the key to `func2`
5) Repeat `4` and `5` until all `10` keys are read
```

`Ordering` is not important

Comment: Can you explain in detail what do you want to do?

Comment: Are these key  like `sha512-T9JWj==`, `sha512-lcddfd==` fixed name or do they change according to reponse?

Comment: Keys are fixed names and not changing.  Added more details at the end of my questions

Comment: By first key value pair in  ` Loop through first key value pair`, you mean  only "sha512-T9JWj==": [
        "mykey1597855209",
        "mykey159785520915978552101597855212"
      ],?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a map doesn't actually have any ordering. You can retrieve all the entries from the map and pick the first 10 that are returned, but there is no guaranteed order to how the entries will be returned.

```
const entries = Object.entries(map).slice(0,10);
for (const [key, values] of entries) {
    func1(key);
    for (const value of values) {
        func2(value);
    }
}
```

Or, in more functional style

```
Object.entries(map).slice(0,10).forEach(([key, values]) => {
    func1(key);
    values.forEach(value => func2(value));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can use Reflect.ownkeys()
then it is simple to slice it to your prefer length and loop over it.

```js
map = {
      "sha512-T9JWj==": [
        "mykey1597855209",
        "mykey159785520915978552101597855212"
      ],
      "sha512-lcddfd==": [
        "mykey15978552091597855210"
      ],
      "sha512-abcdfd==": [
        "otherkey15978552091597855210"
      ]
    }

Reflect.ownKeys(map).slice(0, 10).forEach((k)=>{
  console.log(k); // your func1
  console.dir(map[k]) // your func2
})
```